# Error:could not create the Java Virtual Machine Error:A fatal exception has occured.Program will exit

Tags: java, java-8

I have just installed Java SE Development Kit 8u91 on my 64 bit Windows-10 OS. I set my *path* variables . I tried **java --version** in my command prompt it gave me an error.

```
c:\Users\Onlymanu>java --version
Unrecognized option: --version    
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

But when i tried **java -version** it worked.

I tried initializing *_JAVA_OPTIONS*  environment variable and ever tried re-installation none of them worked. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Try "java -version" ... only one dash. But still, very strange.

Comment: "java -version" is working for me no problem with that but i only hace problem with "java --version"

Comment: `--version` is not an acceptable option to use with `java`

Comment: I don't get your question - if you already found out that `java -version` works, what do you want to know?

Answer (score 109):

I think you have put command like `java -VERSION`. This is in capital letters
You need to put all command in lowercase letters

```
javac -version
java -version
```

All characters must be in lowercase letter

Comment: Please format commands appropriately. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in my case, it was `java --version` double slash instead of `java -version`

Comment: in my case, java -version would not work, until I first did javac -version :/

Answer (score 67):

I was facing a similar issue. Actually the command is :

```
java -version and not java --version.
```

You will get output something like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 64):

Java 8:

```
java -version
```

Java 9+:

```
java --version
```

Answer (score 31):

the command should be **java -version**

Answer (score 13):

Try executing below command,

```
java -help
```

It gives option as,

> -version      print product version and exit

**java -version** is the correct command to execute

Answer (score 10):

`--version` is a valid option from JDK 9 and it is not a valid option until JDK 8 hence you get the below:

```
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

You can try installing JDK 9 or any version later and check for `java --version` it will work.

Alternately, from the installed JDK 9 or later versions you can see from `java -help` the below two options will be available:

```
    -version      print product version to the error stream and exit
    --version     print product version to the output stream and exit
```

where as in JDK 8 you will only have below when you execute `java -help`

```
    -version      print product version and exit
```

I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 9):

This happens because the CMD doesn't recognize the "java --version" try writing "java -version"
when "java --version" it tries to create a JVM. IT Fails because that's wrong command.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your command is **wrong**.

Linux

`java -- version`

macOS

`java -version`

You can't use those commands other way around.

Answer (score 5):

```
java -version
java -showversion
```

Both commands work In Linux 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

As someone has pointed out before you get that error because `java --version` doesn't exist as a command before java 9+. I had a similar issue where I installed the latest version of jdk and the command would still return the exact same error you have provided. In my case the error came from having an older version of java still installed on my system.

To fix this, since you're on Windows go to "Settings"->"Apps & Features" and then search for "Java". If you find that a you still have an older version of Java installed, particularly one before Java 9 like Java 8 for example, uninstall that version and install a newer version instead. Don't forget to configure the "Environment Variables" afterwards.